# adding content tag to an input field inside a template

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, html5-template

I am trying to use the new html5 template tag to make a semi-generic form that can be placed in multiple use cases without using too much javascript.

Here is a fiddle showing what I have http://jsfiddle.net/684uH/

my goal is to replace the "Name" in the placeholder text with what would would typically be found in the `<content>` tag

a hypothetical example to get my point accross would be:

```
<div id = "hoster">
    <span class = "inputPlaceholder">Special Name</span>
</div>

<template id = "im-a-template">
    <input type="text" placeholder = <content select = ".inputPlaceholder"></content>>
</template>
```

Is there a way to do something similar or is the only way using javascript to set it manually?

Answer (score -1):

Use XSLT on the client to do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="html5.xhtml"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            >
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" version="" indent="yes" standalone="no" media-type="text/html" omit-xml-declaration="no" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />

<!-- Run default templates on the xsl-stylesheet element above-->
<xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Run this template on the root node -->
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="hoster">
        <span class="inputPlaceholder">Special Name</span>
      </div>

      <!-- Reuse the value of the node with the inputPlaceholder class -->
      <template id="im-a-template">
        <input type="text" placeholder="{//node()[@class='inputPlaceholder']}"/>
      </template>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Use the following process:

- Save as `html5.xhtml` (or change the `<?xml-stylesheet href` to the name of your choice)
- Open in the browser
- Add script tags to run the `<template>` polyfill of your choice

**References**

- [Self-Referencing Stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/Math/XSL/Overview-tech.html#self-style)
- [HTML Standard, 4.12.1.4: Interaction of script elements and XSLT](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#scriptTagXSLT)
- [HTML Standard, Infrastructure: Interactions with XPath and XSLT](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#interactions-with-xpath-and-xslt)